# How can I upgrade the Ubuntu 18.04.3 kernel to 5.0

Tags: kernel

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS with kernel version 4.15.0-55-generic.

How can I upgrade the kernel to 5.0? I have run the `update-manager -d` command already.

Comment: NOT a duplicate, this question is specific for 18.04. The actual answer, thankfully, appears below. The link to the duplicate only complicates matters for people ONLY searching for an answer for 18.04 as there are too many details not specifically dealing with this distribution.

Answer (score 4):

Enable HWE or the Hardware Enablement Stack

DESKTOP

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

SERVER

```
 sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

*fyi:  If you install Ubuntu 18.04 using 18.04.2 or later ISOs, the HWE kernel is the default.*